# Migrate Project from sharpdevelop 4.4 to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, migrate, sharpdevelop

i need to migrate a project from Sharpdevelop 4.4 to Visual Studio 2010. and when i do i have a errors. I have a example very simple! I try i create the project and the main form is like this!
Mainform.vb

```
Public Partial Class MainForm
    Public Sub New()
        ' The Me.InitializeComponent call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        Me.InitializeComponent()

        '
        ' TODO : Add constructor code after InitializeComponents
        '
    End Sub

    Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub
    End Class
```

And Mainform.Designer.vb

```
Partial Class MainForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Designer variable used to keep track of non-visual components.
    ''' </summary>
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Disposes resources used by the form.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This method is required for Windows Forms designer support.
    ''' Do not change the method contents inside the source code editor. The Forms designer might
    ''' not be able to load this method if it was changed manually.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.SuspendLayout
        '
        'button1
        '
        Me.button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(88, 88)
        Me.button1.Name = "button1"
        Me.button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.button1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.button1.Text = "button1"
        Me.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
        AddHandler Me.button1.Click, AddressOf Me.Button1Click
        '
        'MainForm
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6!, 13!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 262)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.button1)
        Me.Name = "MainForm"
        Me.Text = "pruebadeimportacion"
        Me.ResumeLayout(false)
    End Sub
    Private button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    End Class
```

when i open the project in Visual studio this is run ok, but when i do a modification and save this, the files looks like this

The file Mainform.vb

```
Public Partial Class MainForm
Public Sub New()
    ' The Me.InitializeComponent call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
    Me.InitializeComponent()

    '
    ' TODO : Add constructor code after InitializeComponents
    '
End Sub

Sub Button1Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

And the file:Mainform.Designer.vb

```
Partial Class MainForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Designer variable used to keep track of non-visual components.
    ''' </summary>
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Disposes resources used by the form.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This method is required for Windows Forms designer support.
    ''' Do not change the method contents inside the source code editor. The Forms designer might
    ''' not be able to load this method if it was changed manually.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'button1
        '
        Me.button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(88, 88)
        Me.button1.Name = "button1"
        Me.button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.button1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.button1.Text = "button1"
        Me.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'MainForm
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 262)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.button1)
        Me.Name = "MainForm"
        Me.Text = "pruebadeimportacion"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Private button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    End Class
```

In this changes appears an error, "Error Handler require ... WithEvents" (BC30506)
Visual Studio change the code, and with all subs do the same modification. For this example:
Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Change for this:
Sub Button1Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
This is for all subs in the project, Please help!
This error appears in all events the project, its a example but in a program very long i have many errors, and fix all is very dificult, exist some solution to this process? please help! thanks

Comment: SharpDevelop 4.4 was released in 2015, http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/download/Default.aspx so it is more likely to be compatible with VS 2012/2013/2015. Your VS2010 is too old, which might not match VB.NET version.

Comment: Your .designer is missing `WithEvents` for your controls. For example `Private WithEvents button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button`

Comment: I install VS 2017 and the results are the same, same error.! i need a fix error I have the same error in the whole program, I need some way to solve it in a simple way, to make it simple, is there any way? Create a program?